# php if sentence not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm not very expierenced at coding in PHP. I'm stuck at problem where I need to merge 2 arrays, but basically if array with `$aFilter` the code is not compiling.

```
$aFilterParams =array(
        'all'=>1
        ,'all_status'=>1
        );
$aFilter = array();

if (getString('action')=='filter')
{

    $aFilter['user_name']=getString('user_name');
    $aFilter['user_surname']=getString('user_surname');
    $aFilter['order_id']=getString('order_id');
    $aFilter['email']=getString('email');
    $aFilter['date_from']=getString('date_from');
    $aFilter['date_to']=getString('date_to');
    //$aFilter['type_id']=getNumber('type_id');
    $$oDirectHTML->SetVar($aFilter);

    array_merge($aFilterParams, $aFilter);


}
```

Please help.

Comment: Without the `getString` function, we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Try var_dump() or print_r() of each of the arrays before merging. As Daan pointed out, without knowing getString() it's hard to answer.

Comment: Also, how confident are you about `$$oDirectHTML`?

Comment: @DaanMeijer basically this code is for search in webpage and im trying to make if sentece work but when i var_dump($aFillter) it returns "array(0) { }"

Answer (score 4):

You must to assign the result of `array_merge` to the `$aFilter` variable or to the `$aFilterParams` variable, depending on your needs:

```
$aFilter = array_merge($aFilterParams, $aFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following two lines looks suspicious to me.
  `//$aFilter['type_id']=getNumber('type_id');`
  `$$oDirectHTML->SetVar($aFilter);`
Can you change  `$$oDirectHTML->SetVar($aFilter);` to `$oDirectHTML->SetVar($aFilter);` and try.